# Mitmproxy, push own WebSocket message

Tags: python, websocket, mitmproxy

I inspect a HTTPS WebSocket traffic with **Mitmproxy**. Currently I can read/edit WS messages with:

```
class Intercept:
    def websocket_message(self, flow):
        print(flow.messages[-1])

def start():
    return Intercept()
```

.. as attached script to Mitmproxy.

How do I push/inject my own message to the client? Not edit existing one, but add a new message.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `inject.websocket`:

```py
from mitmproxy import ctx

class Intercept:
    def websocket_message(self, flow):
        print(flow.messages[-1])
        to_client = True
        ctx.master.commands.call("inject.websocket", flow, to_client, b"Hello World!", True)

def start():
    return Intercept()
```

There are [more examples](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#websocket-inject-message) in the documentation.